# Can you explain me how does this work?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = df.loc[-df['Retention time (min)'] < 0]
```

Does this mean that it is removing the row where retention time is less than 0 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Simply filter data rows by condition, here:

```
-df['Retention time (min)'] < 0
```

`loc` is not necessary:

```
df = df[-df['Retention time (min)'] < 0]
```

But if need filter also some column `loc` is necessary:

```
df = df.loc[-df['Retention time (min)'] < 0, 'col1']
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Retention time (min)':[-1,2,3,-6,4,5],
                   'b':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})

print (df)
   Retention time (min)  b
0                    -1  4
1                     2  5
2                     3  4
3                    -6  5
4                     4  5
5                     5  4

df1 = df[-df['Retention time (min)'] < 0]
print (df1)
   Retention time (min)  b
1                     2  5
2                     3  4
4                     4  5
5                     5  4

df2 = df.loc[-df['Retention time (min)'] < 0, 'b']
print (df2)
1    5
2    4
4    5
5    4
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

And it is same as:

```
df1 = df[df['Retention time (min)'] > 0]
print (df1)
   Retention time (min)  b
1                     2  5
2                     3  4
4                     4  5
5                     5  4

df2 = df.loc[df['Retention time (min)'] > 0, 'b']
print (df2)
1    5
2    4
4    5
5    4
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what does the - symbol symbolises there .Does it mean it is removing that row  ?